# What are the obligatory duties of a grandchild?

Tags: halal-haram, parents, obligation

What are the obligatory duties of a grandchild in Islam.
Also if my parents ask me to take care of my grandparents am i obligated to do so even when my grandparents have 4-5 children. Will it be haram if i refuse? Is is not the duty of their own children to look after them?